# Android studio using emulators with higher API versions

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

so I more or less know my way around android studio there's one issue I don't understand. Why is it when I am working with a project and I try to test it on a higher API version emulator it doesn't really work properly. It just does nothing. Sometimes it will provide the desired output, but that may take a long time and sometimes it is able to provide the desired output. I tried the application on an emulator with the minimum API and it worked fine with no issues.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No problem I just want to know if I can fix the issue of my application not working on phones with a higher API level.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Android Studio's Emulator as it makes my pc slow and most of the times cpu is at 100% so I would use third party emulator and connect that emulator to Android Studio using adb and It works fine for me.

Comment: Can you suggest the emulator that you use?

Comment: @YaseenLatiff Bluestacks works fine for me and its fast for me, i dont have GPU in my PC and i wasnt able to install normal Bluestacks so i installed Bluestacks Hyper-V Model. ( it would be good if you upvote my post and mark it as accepted )

Comment: Thanks man I just upvoted it it won't show because I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).